# how to call header and footer in other wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, header, footer

i have two wordpress websites, 1st website which we can call it
firstsite, and 2nd website and we can call it secondwebsite

i want to include the header and footer of firstsite to be used as
header and footer for secondwebsite

this to allow the header and footer for secondwebsite  to be
dynamically updated from firstsite

i want use secondwebsite to create pages content only, all header and
footer UI and data should be loaded from firstsite

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to include header and footer files by full absolute path to the other file. This is valid only if you have the two websites in the same server. Otherwise, I fear there isn't any other way unfortunately.

For example, in header.php of "secondwebsite", you'll write:

```
include '/the/absolute/path/to/header.php';
```

The same also for footer.php

I hope it can help you.

Comment: this work but it render only the styling and layout.
i want the main menu loaded from DB of firstsite 

all i want that if the webmaster for firstsite edit or remove or update website menu

this effect the main menu of secondwebsite
in other word i want to include firstsite menu into secondwebsite menu

Answer (score 0):

if it's in same Wordpress project you can call functions from wp for example:

```
get_footer();
get_header();
```

you need to call it on your php file where you want the header to appear e.g. in your index.php .
You call the header on the start of your file and the footer in the end.

i hope you mean that what im trying to explain.

greets Jan

Comment: It's in another wordpress project